# MWS API Access Denied error

Tags: java, api, amazon-mws

I am trying to fetch Finances.ListFinancialEvents data using mws api. The api works fine for one account. But when I logout and login with another account ,getting Access Denied error for all accounts previews.

For example if I have two accounts: accountA and accountB.
When I login with accountA everything works fine, later when I logout and login using accountB I get access denied. Even if I login again with accountA I continue getting access denied.
When I restart server and login with accountB works fine, but again switching account causes access denied error for all accounts.

Both are Amazon marketplace USA account. With API enabled for both. What could be the problem.
Any guidance greatly appreciated. 
Amazon API's so messed up ((

Comment: provide code and more details

Comment: Amazon MWS does not have a "login" or "logout". I assume with these terms you are referring to the Sellercentral which has no effect whatsoever on MWS API calls. So in essence: What exactly are you doing and where exactly do you get that "access denied"?